# Regex search efficiency

Tags: ios, regex, swift

I need to find and replace tags in an HTML string. 
What I need is to find few specific custom tags (tagA, tagB, tagC), and replace them with other strings, different for each tag.

What will be more efficient?

- To run a Regex find and replace for each tag
- run one regex search to find all tags, iterate each result and look for its type be the tag name
- other way that I didn't think of

Thanks

Comment: In my opinion, an xpath query first (there are several gorgeous string functions as well) and then replace these tags based on your regex.

Answer (score 0):

The most efficient would be to run a single regex and replace taking into on match value. Don't know about Swift but in Python you can pass a handler to the replace function https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub

A regex can be something like https://regex101.com/r/jE1pE0/1